# How to prevent save() from update created timestamp

Tags: mysql, django

My django app has a table with a datetime field date_created, which is set default to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.  The database is MySQL.
My model

```
class HybImages(models.Model):
    HIGH = 6
    INFORMATIVE = 5
    AVERAGE = 4
    LOW = 3
    QUALITY = (
        ('HI', 'High'),
        ('LO', 'Low'),
        ('AV', 'Average'),
        ('CH', 'Challenged'),
        ('TP', 'Top'),
    )
    pid = models.ForeignKey(Hybrid, db_column='pid', verbose_name='grex', null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    form = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    rank = models.IntegerField(choices=RANK_CHOICES,default=5)
    zoom = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    certainty = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    source_file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
    ...
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
```

When I update a record to change a certain field (say, rank).  I did the following:

```
>>> from orchiddb.models import HybImages
>>>
>>> id = 39387
>>> image = HybImages.objects.get(pk=id)
>>> image.date_created
datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 24, 15, 28, 29, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> image.rank = 1
>>> image.save()
>>> image.date_created
datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 31, 14, 14, 51, 852406, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Why did the date_created value changed (and what 852406 stand for)?
What do I have to do to keep date_created unchanged?

Comment: You can use `auto_now_add=True` (create) and `auto_now=True` (update), insteade, thes parameters are used to keep track of the creation and the update.

Comment: Where's your model code?

Comment: I did both auto_now=True and enforce it in the database with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.  Should I remove the database default?

Comment: @dirkgroten I added my model  in th epost

Comment: `auto_now=True` will update it every time you save again. Use `auto_now_add=True` instead. And yes, remove the database enforcement, seems to do the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Suggestion: Remove `null=True` for both fields, but also for all your `CharField`s. A `CharField` should not be null, otherwise it can have two different empty values (null and '')

Comment: Thank you @dirkgroten. Removing NULL=True does the trick!